# Applying a map across several columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a map across several columns in pandas to reflect when data is invalid. When data is invalid in my df['Count'] column, I want to set my df['Value'], df['Lower Confidence Interval'], df['Upper Confidence Interval'] and df['Denominator'] columns to -1.

This is a sample of the dataframe:

```
Count   Value       Lower Confidence Interval  Upper Confidence Interval  Denominator
121743  54.15758428 53.95153779                54.36348867                224794
280     91.80327869 88.18009411                94.38654088                305
430     56.95364238 53.39535553                60.44152684                755
970     70.54545455 68.0815009                 72.89492873                1375
nan             
70      28.57142857 23.27957213                34.52488678                245
125     62.5        55.6143037                 68.91456314                200
```

Currently, I am trying:

```
set_minus_1s = {np.nan: -1, '*': -1, -1: -1}
```

then:

```
df[['Value', 'Count', 'Lower Confidence Interval', 'Upper Confidence Interval', 'Denominator']] = df['Count'].map(set_minus_1s)
```

and getting the error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Is there any way of chaining the column references to make one call to the map rather than have separate lines for each column to call the `set_minus_1s` dictionary as a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and replace all rows where not [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) after apply `map`:

```
val = df['Count'].map(set_minus_1s)
print (val)
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4   -1.0
5    NaN
6    NaN
Name: Count, dtype: float64

cols =['Value','Count','Lower Confidence Interval','Upper Confidence Interval','Denominator']
df[cols] = df[cols].where(val.isnull(), val, axis=0)
print (df)
      Count      Value  Lower Confidence Interval  Upper Confidence Interval  \
0  121743.0  54.157584                  53.951538                  54.363489   
1     280.0  91.803279                  88.180094                  94.386541   
2     430.0  56.953642                  53.395356                  60.441527   
3     970.0  70.545455                  68.081501                  72.894929   
4      -1.0  -1.000000                  -1.000000                  -1.000000   
5      70.0  28.571429                  23.279572                  34.524887   
6     125.0  62.500000                  55.614304                  68.914563   

   Denominator  
0     224794.0  
1        305.0  
2        755.0  
3       1375.0  
4         -1.0  
5        245.0  
6        200.0
```

---

```
cols = ['Value', 'Count', 'Lower Confidence Interval', 'Upper Confidence Interval', 'Denominator']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(val.notnull(), val, axis=0)
print (df)
      Count      Value  Lower Confidence Interval  Upper Confidence Interval  \
0  121743.0  54.157584                  53.951538                  54.363489   
1     280.0  91.803279                  88.180094                  94.386541   
2     430.0  56.953642                  53.395356                  60.441527   
3     970.0  70.545455                  68.081501                  72.894929   
4      -1.0  -1.000000                  -1.000000                  -1.000000   
5      70.0  28.571429                  23.279572                  34.524887   
6     125.0  62.500000                  55.614304                  68.914563   

   Denominator  
0     224794.0  
1        305.0  
2        755.0  
3       1375.0  
4         -1.0  
5        245.0  
6        200.0
```

Comment: Sorry, my rep was too low - and now it isn't! Upvoted.